Not getting the required angle between two planes
I want to find the angle between two given planes $\Pi_1 : x-y+z=0$ and $\Pi_2: -x+4y-z=3.$
I first found their normal vectors, which are $\begin{pmatrix}
1 \\
-1 \\
1
\end{pmatrix}$ and
$\begin{pmatrix}
-1 \\
4 \\
-1
\end{pmatrix},$ respectively.
Then, using the cosine-rule formula with inner product $$\cos(\theta) = \frac{\mathbf{n_1} \cdot \mathbf{n_2}}{\|\mathbf{n_1}\| \|\mathbf{n_2}\|},$$ where $\mathbf{n_1} \cdot \mathbf{n_2}=-6$, $\|\mathbf{n_1}\| = \sqrt{3},$ $\|\mathbf{n_2}\|= 3\sqrt{2},$ I got $\cos(\theta) = -\frac{\sqrt{6}}{3}.$
But the given answer shows that $\theta$ is given by $\cos(\theta) = \pm \sqrt{\frac{2}{3}}.$ I'm not sure what the problem is. Maybe I'm misunderstanding the question, or perhaps I'm missing some important detail.

$$n_1=\hat i-\hat j+\hat k$$
$$n_2=-\hat i+4\hat j-\hat k$$
$$\cos\theta=\left|\frac{n_1 \cdot n_2}{|n_1||n_2|}\right|=\left|\frac{-1-4-1}{(\sqrt3)(\sqrt{18})}\right|=\frac{2}{\sqrt{6}}\implies \theta=cos^{-1}\left(\frac{2}{\sqrt6}\right)$$$\left(\frac{2}{\sqrt{6}}=\frac{\sqrt2}{\sqrt3}\right)$

@David Gao  the work‘s been already posted

@whatamidoing why the answer could be both negative and positive

$\sqrt{6}/3 = \sqrt{2/3}$.

@YukaiHUA If $x$ is a normal vector, then so is $-x$, which is why the answer can be either positive or negative.

@David Gao Oh! i never notice that point, have we learnt that in high school?(PS:just curious, how to prove that)

@YukaiHUA I have no idea what is or isn’t taught in the high school curriculum where you’re from. But both of my points are quite elementary and obvious, so I’d assume so.

One way to write the definition of a plane is $\hat{n}\cdot (\vec{r}-\vec{r}_0)=0$. But then you can multiply both sides by $-1$ to get $(-\hat{n})\cdot (\vec{r}-\vec{r}_0)=0$, so $-\hat{n}$ is just as legitimate a normal vector as $\hat{n}$ was.


Then, using $$\cos(\theta) = \frac{\mathbf{n_1} \cdot \mathbf{n_2}}{\|\mathbf{n_1}\| \|\mathbf{n_2}\|},$$ I got $\cos(\theta) = -\frac{\sqrt{6}}{3}.$

The angle $\theta$ between two plane is conventionally defined on $\left[0,\frac{\pi}2\right]$ and given by $$\cos(\theta) =\left| \frac{\mathbf{n_1} \cdot \mathbf{n_2}}{\|\mathbf{n_1}\| \|\mathbf{n_2}\|}\right|.$$ So, for your exercise, $\theta$ is given by $$\cos(\theta)=\frac{\sqrt{6}}{3}.$$
The two answers that your textbook gives are equivalent to each other. Think about it: isn't saying that two planes form $145^\circ$ essentially the same as saying that they form $35^\circ$ ?
